# const vs #define in modern compilers

Tags: c++

I've read a few things saying that a `#define` doesn't take up any memory, but a colleague at work was very insistent that modern compilers don't have any differences when it comes to const int/strings.

```
#define STD_VEC_HINT 6;
const int stdVecHint = 6;
```

The conversation came about because an old bit of code that was being modernised that dealt with encryption that had its key as a #define.

I always thought that a variable would end up getting a memory address which would show its contents, but maybe compiling under release removes such stuff.

Comment: By "modern compilers" he probably meant "actually very old compilers, too".

Comment: The even better question though is: why would you care?

Comment: @PlasmaHH in the case of the encryption key is why we care.

Comment: @PhilCK: why would you care because its encryption related code?

Comment: @PlasmaHH the topic came up because there was a concern that the key would easily appear in a memory dump attack.

Comment: @PhilCK: The code has to process it, it will always be accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good compiler will not allocate space for a const variable that can be elided. In C++, const variables at the module scope are also implicity static in visibility, so it's easier for the compiler to optimize out the variable as well. The link time optimization feature of GCC helps as well to do cross-module optimization.

Don't forget the even more important fact that const variables have proper scoping and type safety, which are missing from #define.

Answer (score 1):

As with so many thinks, it depends..!

A `#define` will just inject the constant straight into your code, so it won't take up any memory. The same is potentially true for a `const`.

However, you can take the address of a `const`:

```
const int *value = &stdVecHint;
```

And since you're taking its address the compiler will need to store the constant in memory in order to generate an address, so in this case it will require memory.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is likely to replace occurrences with `stdVecHint` with the literal `6` everywhere it is used. An address and memory space will be taken up if you take its address explicitly, but then again this is a moot point since you couldn't do that with the `STD_VEC_HINT`. Pedantically, yes, `stdVecHint` is a variable with internal linkage and every translation unit that sees the definition will have its own copy of it. In practice, it shouldn't increase the memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-processor command uses this type of command like #define ,....

and no need to allocate memory because

and change name of constant [#define pi 3.14] like pi with 3.14 and then compile code

but in const command [const float pi=3.14;] need to memory allocation

For compatibility with older versions of the preprocessor is no problem, but future unclear

be successfull